# jsoup not support another language?

Tags: android, css, jsoup

want show specific div of web . my code correct and work for English sit but for example not work with Arabic Language even not fixed in standard position Although that sit have responsive coding.

this is my code:

```
public class card_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

public WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.card_activity);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        final String receivingdata = b.getString("Key");


        webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                String html = "";
                try {
                    Document document = Jsoup.connect(receivingdata).timeout(20000).get();
                    Element elements=document.select("div.base-box:nth-child(2)").first();
                    html = elements.toString();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return html;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String html) {

                String mime = "text/html";
                String encoding = "utf-8";
                webView.loadData(html, mime, encoding);

            }
        }.execute();
}
}
```

and this my result for another language:
[image]

How can show that part of sit in fix position and correct language?

Comment: Can you share the URL? You could try `Jsoup.connect(receivingdata).header("Accept-Language", "ar").timeout(20000).get();`

Comment: @HigherCoding not work . http://memaraneha.ir/%db%8c%da%a9%d9%be%d8%a7%d8%b1%da%86%da%af%db%8c-%d9%87%d9%85%d8%a7%d9%87%d9%86%da%af%db%8c-%d8%b7%d8%b1%d8%a7%d8%ad%db%8c-%d8%af%d8%a7%d8%ae%d9%84%db%8c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after so many try i recognize cant do that with jsoup setting . just use `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,html, mime, encoding,null);`instead `webView.loadData(html, mime, encoding);` and show any language easy!

Answer (score 0):

I think this relates to the charset attribute missing in the HTTP response Content-Type header. Jsoup will use the platform default charset when parsing the HTML so you will need to read the URL as an InputStream and manually specify the charset in Jsoup parse() method.

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(new URL(receivingdata).openStream(), "ISO-639-2", url);
Element elements=document.select("div.base-box:nth-child(2)").first();
for (Node node : elements.childNodes()) {
    if (node instanceof TextNode) {
        System.out.println(((TextNode) node).text().trim());
    }
}
```

Comment: what is url (last parametr in document)? and  for (Node node : elements.childNodes()) to android sutido suggestion become to { for (org.jsoup.nodes.Node node : elements.childNodes()) {